# What's g:statusline_winid?

Tags: statusline, variables

When I do `:h 'statusline'` I can see

> The *g:statusline_winid* variable will be set to the **window-ID** of the
> window that the status line belongs to.

But `:set statusline=[window_id\:%{g:statusline_winid}]` does not work.

Actually I don't have any problem with this because I can use `winnr()`, but the mystery remains.

What's `g:statusline_winid`? Is it still available? Or my use was wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation say:

```
When the option starts with "%!" then it is used as an expression,
evaluated and the result is used as the option value.  Example:

    :set statusline=%!MyStatusLine()

The g:statusline_winid variable will be set to the window-ID of the
window that the status line belongs to.
```

So if you for example do:

```vim
fun! MyStatusLine()
    return "WID: " . g:statusline_winid
endfun

set statusline=%!MyStatusLine()
```

Your status-line will be:

```
WID: NNNN
```

where `NNNN` is the window-ID. Or put another way: the variable `g:statusline_winid` is not set unless you use a call with `statusline=%!SomeFun()`

Also note that the variable is unset after function exits.

## winid vs winnr

As for what it is:

`winid`: Each window has it's own ID. When you start Vim first window typically has ID `1000`. If you open a new window by e.g. `:split` the new window get ID `1001` if you close that split and open another that get `1002` etc.

`winnr`: Each window has a number based on it's position. Upper left is 1. You can for example have:

```
+------+-----+
|      |  2  |
|  1   +-----+
|      |  3  |
|      |     |
+------+-----+
```

That is: `winnr` is not persistent. It all depends on the layout. If you close window number `1` in example above, 2 becomes 1 and 3 becomes 2.

`winid` is a way to keep track of a window independent of layout changes.